# Failing to validate server certificate with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, soap, ssl, openssl, betfair

I have written a SOAP client using OpenSSL (written in C++ on Ubuntu 12.04) but it currently works without checking the server security certificate. This is the function I am using to set up the connection and checking the certificate

```
bool bInitialiseSSL(SSL_CTX* &ctx, SSL* &ssl, BIO* &bio)
{
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());  
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    if (bio == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);    
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        return false;
    }

    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);

    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
    char target[]  = "api.betfair.com:https";

    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, target);
    BIO_set_nbio(bio,1);
    while (1) {
        if (BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0) {
            if (!BIO_should_retry(bio)) {
                cout << "Connect failed." << endl;
                BIO_free_all(bio);
                SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (BIO_do_handshake(bio) <= 0) {
        BIO_free_all(bio);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        return false;
    }

    X509 *cert;
    bool bValid  = false;
    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); 
    if ( cert != NULL ) {
        long res = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
        if (res == X509_V_OK) {
            bValid = true;
        } else {
            cout << "Error in security validation: " << res << endl;
        }
        X509_free(cert);   
    }
    return bValid;
}
```

This works fine but the return value of SSL_get_verify_result is 20 which corresponds to

> X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY: unable to get local
>   issuer certificate

I have read some of the OpenSSL documentation for their functions but it is not particularly user friendly. I have looked at a number of web tutorials and I cannot see what I am doing wrong. My software worked perfectly before I tried to implement the certificate checking but I cannot see what I need to do. Do I need to configure settings on my machine? The server is betfair which is supposedly very secure and I find it hard to believe that they do not have valid SSL certificates. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the certificates of the server.

- If it is a public valid certificate, you can include the CA certs file into SSL_CTX.

code:

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method()); 
// You can load CA certs into SSL_CTX
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, cafile, NULL); // cafile: CA PEM certs file
```

You can download the public CA certs file from cURL website [CA Certs from mozilla.org](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

- If it is a private certs, and you have the certificate file, you can use `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` instead of `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - how do I discover if it is a private or public certificate?

Comment: If it is an external server, you should try the first alternative.

Comment: `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file` is for your private key as a client if you're using a client certificate. This has nothing to do at all with having a "private" certificate (that doesn't really make sense in this context). If you have a separate CA that's not on the default Mozilla list (or whichever list you choose to use), just add it to the main CA list.

Comment: This actually solved my problem when I copied the cacert.pem file from that link. I am going to accept this answer, but can you tell me why I do not have this file on my machine? I have a mozilla directory that contains many .crt files, but no .pem file? Why is this?

Comment: You always need to get the trusted CA certs from a public well known place. All the TLS/SSL implementations have the trusted CA certs, such like JRE, Windows, OpenSSL, Firefox. Keep in mind, with the time goes on, some root CA certs will be expired. After that you will need to download the up to date CA certs again, and apply to your application.